# Help using NSZombieEnabled

Tags: iphone, debugging, nszombie

I'm trying to debug some code.  I ran the static analyzer, and thought I fixed a memory leak, and now I get an error when I switch between two tabs.  Here is my code when I switch between the 2nd tab and first tab:

```
        if (_sortButton != nil) {
            self.SortButton = nil;
            NSMutableArray *barItems = [[self.MainToolbar items] mutableCopy];
            [barItems removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [self.MainToolbar setItems:barItems]; // bad access here
            [barItems release];
        }
```

I keep getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the self.MainToolbar setItems line.  I added the NSZombieEnabled as an environment variable, set a break point at that bad access line, but I do not get anything printed to the console when either stepping after the breakpoint, hitting continue after the breakpoint, etc.  Am I using this correctly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far easier to use than NSZombieEnabled, is to use `Profile` instead when running and select the NSZombie instrument.

This requires XCode4.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding a ,nil at the end of a list of objects for the NSArray.

```
[self.MainToolbar setItems:barItems,nil]
```